# Embed videos from Youtube & Vimeo in the same player

Tags: javascript, youtube, vimeo

I'm trying to embed both Youtube & Vimeo videos in the same player,
I found this https://github.com/jakiestfu/Youtube-TV and it looks exactly how I want it, except its purely youtube videos.

I want to be able to provide youtube & vimeo links that will be embedded like the Youtube-TV plugin.

I googled and searched stackoverflow but no use.

Any tips where to start?

Comment: helpful for you https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406725-youtube-video-embed

Comment: @WaqasAhmed Thanks a lot! but this looks like another plugin (similar to Youtube-TV), they didn't mention vimeo support (as in both video types at the same time)

Comment: No, I cannot imagine it's possible.  Most you could do, is make something where it looks like you're doing what you want to do.  You could use the same div to embed the players in, you could use the same control buttons, but surely not the same player.

Comment: @EmmanuelDelay I'm afraid I didn't get exactly what you mean, can I have youtube & vimeo videos displayed on the right panel in the player to choose from? I want to be able to play 1 video at a time (either Youtube or Vimeo)